# Proving that $\frac{x^n}{1+x^n}$ converges simply but not uniformly

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

We have that

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{x^n}{1+x^n} = 1$$

I want to show that for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists $n_0$ such that

$$n>n_0\implies \left|\frac{x^n}{1+x^n}-1\right| = \left|\frac{1}{1+x^n}\right|<\epsilon$$

I did:

$$n_0 =\log_{x}\frac{1}{\epsilon} $$

so

$$n>n_0\implies x^n>x^{\log_{x}\frac{1}{\epsilon}} = \frac{1}{\epsilon}$$

therefore:

$$\frac{1}{1+x^n}<\frac{1}{x^n}<\epsilon$$

Am I right?

Now, I need to show that this convergence is not uniform. I need to show that there exists an $\epsilon>0$ such that for

$$n>n_0 \implies \left|\frac{1}{1+x^n}-1\right|>\epsilon$$

but I'm unable to do it

Comment: Note that while not incorrect the way you have it, one usually wants $n_0$ to be an integer, and $\log_{x}\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ rarely is one.

Comment: This should be for $x>1$, right?

Comment: What is the domain ? is it $[0,+\infty[$ ? (because, for $n$ odd the function is not defined at $-1$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pointwise limit $f$ is defined by

$f(x)=1 $ if $|x|>1,$

$ f(1)= \frac{1}{2}$ and

$f(x)=0$ if $|x|<1$.

but

$\forall n\geq 0 \;x\mapsto \frac{x^n}{1+x^n}$ is continuous at $x=1$

and $f$ is not continuous at $x=1$

thus, the convergence is not uniform at $(-\infty,-1)\cup(-1,+\infty)$.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly there is a problem with domain. Hopefully the following will help.

Pointwise convergence on $D \subset \mathbb R$: 
$$\forall x \in D \forall \varepsilon >0 \exists n_0(\varepsilon, x) \in \mathbb{N}\forall n \geq n_0(\varepsilon, x) \implies |f_n(x) - f(x)| \leq \varepsilon,$$

Negation of Pointwise convergence on $D \subset \mathbb R$:
$$\exists x \in D \exists \varepsilon >0 \forall n_0 \in \mathbb{N}\exists n(n_0) \geq n_0 \implies |f_n(x) - f(x)| \leq \varepsilon,$$

Uniform convergence on $D \subset \mathbb R$: 
$$\forall \varepsilon >0 \exists n_0(\varepsilon) \in \mathbb{N}\forall n \geq n_0(\varepsilon)\forall x \in D \implies |f_n(x) - f(x)| \leq \varepsilon,$$

Negation of Uniform convergence on $D \subset \mathbb R$:

$$\exists \varepsilon >0 \forall n_0 \in \mathbb{N}\exists n(n_0) \geq n_0\exists x(n_0) \in D \implies |f_n(x) - f(x)| \leq \varepsilon.$$

When I write $n_0(\varepsilon, x)$ I mean that $n_0$ depends on $\varepsilon, x$. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you need to restrict your domain of convergence of $x$ to be $(1,\infty)$ to deduce that pointwise convergence to be $1$ for each such $x$. If you restrict such $x$ to be $[0,1)$, then the pointwise convergence is $0$. For such $x\in(1,\infty)$, the convergence is not uniform. Assuming the contrary that it is, then choose some $N\in{\bf{N}}$ such that for all $n\geq N$ and $x\in(1,\infty)$, then $\left|\dfrac{x^{n}}{1+x^{n}}-1\right|<\dfrac{1}{3}$. We have then $\dfrac{1}{1+x^{N}}<\dfrac{1}{3}$ for all $x\in(1,\infty)$. Taking $x\downarrow 1$, then $\dfrac{1}{2}<\dfrac{1}{3}$, which is of course absurd.